Go the Distance
What are the two methods of finding an answer?
(CSV for the numbers)
1.01285590707,0.187144092933,1.16921005714,-0.159210057136,1.14616537324,0.0938346267569,1.22280897014,-0.132808970138


Welcome to PSE!

1st method

 calculate A + B, take the first 2 decimal digits (others are mostly 0), and convert it with A1Z26.

yielding the answer

 TAXI, a reference to Taxicab geometry

2nd method

 calculcate the length of the black line, i.e. √(A^2 + B^2), take the first 2 decimal digits and convert with A1Z26.

yielding

 CROW, a reference to the idiom "as the crow flies", i.e. the most direct path between two points.


Nice! Exactly right.
